# Split rows into multiple rows based on time duration

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

I'm trying to split rows in an excel file based on `Duration`. So if the duration is 50 minutes, I'd like the same row to be split into 5 fields of 10 minute time blocks each. My logic would be to take the duration in the row, count the number of resulting rows by dividing duration by 10 and give me 10. I would want to do this for hundreds or thousands of rows.

[image: Screenshot]

If it helps, I'm on Excel for Mac Version 16.18.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few hints:

- To insert 4 rows below a cell, use 
  *cell*.[Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset)(1, 0).[Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)(4, 1).[EntireRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirerow).[Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert) xlShiftDown
- To fill cells with a formula that adds ten minutes to the cell above, use 
  *cell*.Offset(1, 0).Resize(4, 1).[FormulaR1C1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formular1c1) = "=R[-1]C+[TIME](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/time-function-9a5aff99-8f7d-4611-845e-747d0b8d5457)(0, 10, 0)"
- Start at the bottom row and move up